# php If worth of html form is operated

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making the login page in php.

However, no If worth of blank check of html form is operated (line4)

After entering in the html of the form, even if you press the login does not have moved if statement.

Since the cause is not know, I want you to tell me

```
if (isset($_POST["login"])) {//PUSH login button

   //form blank check
  if ($_POST["email"] = '') {
    $error['email'] = "blank";
  } else if ($_POST["pass"] = '') {
    $error['pass'] = "blank";
  }
}

if(!empty($_POST['email'])){

//email & password　verification
 if($_POST['email'] != '' && $_POST['pass'] != ''){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = SHA1($_POST['pass']);
    $query = "select * from human";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      if($data['email'] == $email) {  //form email & password
         if($data['pass'] === $pass) {
           setcookie('email', $email, time()+(60*60*24*3));
           setcookie('pass', $pass, time()+(60*60*24*3));
           setcookie('name', $date['name'], time()+(60*60*24*3));
             exit();
         }else{
           $error['match'] = "anmatch";  //Mismatch Error
         }
      }
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="" method="post">
        <dl>
            <dt>email</dt>
            <dd>
                <input type="text" name="email" size="35" maxlength="255"
          value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
          <?php if($error['email'] == 'blank'): ?>
            <p><font color="red">* Input email</font></p>
          <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <dt>password</dt>
            <dd>
                <input type="password" name="pass" size="35" maxlength="255"
          value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']); ?>">
          <?php if($error['pass'] == 'blank'): ?>
            <p><font color="red">* Input password</font></p>
          <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="sigh in">
    </form>
```

Comment: this line: `if ($_POST["email"] = '') { ` is not a comparison, but an assignation. Replace it with `if ($_POST["email"] == '') {` (note the double `=`.

Comment: imo, fyi,  1) there is no need for separate cookies. 2) for security reasons don't  store user identify information in the cookie. It can be read quite easily. Instead. Store the 'hashed' id of the user record in the cookie and the 'hashed' id in the user. That way it is safe and only uses one cookie.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstly as mentioned in the comments, you are assigning a value in your if statements. Also as a second point I'd guess because your condition is a nested `else if` the first assignment is always true so the second condition will never be tested.

```
//form blank check
if ($_POST["email"] = '') {
$error['email'] = "blank";
} else if ($_POST["pass"] = '') {
$error['pass'] = "blank";
}
```

The second condition statement will only evaluate when the first is `false`

You should try checking each variable independently nand make sure you use `==`

```
//form blank check
if ($_POST["email"] == '') {
$error['email'] = "blank";
}
if ($_POST["pass"] == '') {
$error['pass'] = "blank";
}
```